# android cardview only show the last result the right amount of times

Tags: android-cardview, android-database

i'm new to android and java. 
i made a cardview and populated it with a simple loop like so:

```
private ArrayList<DataObject> getTheData(){
    ArrayList res = new ArrayList<DataObject>();

    for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++){
        DataObject obj = new DataObject("shit","happen");
        res.add(index,obj);
    }
    return res;
}
```

it worked. now i created a database and want to populate it with this data. so i have this:

```
    public ArrayList<DataObject> getData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ArrayList res = null;
    try {
        res = new ArrayList<DataObject>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM quotes a LEFT JOIN authors b ON b.author_id=a.quote_author";

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {

                    Log.d("CHECKDB",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("first_name")) + " " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("last_name")));
                    Log.d("CHECKDB2",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("quote_text")));
                    DataObject obj = new DataObject(
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("first_name")) + " " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("last_name")),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("quote_text"))
                    );
                    res.add(obj);

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());

            }

        }
    } catch (SQLiteException se) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
    } finally {
        if (db != null)
            db.close();
    }


    return res;
}
```

the log show all the results, but when i run the app i get the last result the right amount of times. in this case 4 quotes in my database, so i see 4 but the last one 4 times.

please , since i'm new to it, good explanations will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the issue was that my dataobject attributes were set to static